# EF Core 2.2 eager loading navigation properties related data problem

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

i am using EF core 2.2 with Postgresql and code first approach.
these are my classes:

```
public class SchoolContext : DbContext
{
    public SchoolContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

}

public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```

i see DDL in postgresql and it looks fine. 
The problem is in querying that data. 
I want to use eager loading, and this query does not produce results with related data:

```
        this._context.Blogs
            .Include(blog => blog.Posts)
            .ToList();


SELECT blog."BlogId", blog."Url"
  FROM "Blogs" AS blog
  ORDER BY blog."BlogId"
```

EDIT: This query runs first. If there are no records, it stops here, but if there are some records, then it runs this query:

```
SELECT "blog.Posts"."PostId", "blog.Posts"."BlogId", "blog.Posts"."Title"
  FROM "Posts" AS "blog.Posts"
  INNER JOIN (
      SELECT blog0."BlogId"
      FROM "Blogs" AS blog0
  ) AS t ON "blog.Posts"."BlogId" = t."BlogId"
  ORDER BY t."BlogId"
```

If i do it other way around, i get correct, but it is confusing that i cant get blog with all related posts.

```
this._context.Posts
            .Include(post => post.Blog)
            .ToList();

  SELECT post."PostId", post."BlogId", post."Title", "post.Blog"."BlogId", "post.Blog"."Url"
  FROM "Posts" AS post
  INNER JOIN "Blogs" AS "post.Blog" ON post."BlogId" = "post.Blog"."BlogId"
```

Comment: Why do you thing it doesn't work? Have you actually checked the result set? EF Core eager loading is not using single SQL as EF6.

Comment: @IvanStoev i edited my question. The thing is, it works in sense that i get correct data, but i didn't expect two queries.

Comment: This is [How EF Core Queries Work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/overview). Note 2.c *"One or more queries are sent to the database..."*